# Unable to open password protected Excel document with Office.Interop and C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have got an Excel workbook that is created with Excel.Interop. I save the workbook with `workbook.SaveAs(path, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, "password", "password", false, false)` and then need to close the workbook as a new `worksheet` will be appended at a later stage as part of some sort of automation.

When I try to open the workbook again with `workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly: false, Password: "password");`, the process just hangs, nothing happens, i.e. no exception, nothing.

Below are snippets of what I am attempting:

```
var excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var excelWorkbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks;
var workbook = new object();
//Append means that the a new sheet will be added to the existing workbook, thus the book needs to be opened first.
if (Append)
{
        Exception innerEx = null;
        try
        {
            excelWorkbooks.Open(ExcelOutputPath, ReadOnly: false, Password: "password");
        }
        catch
        {
            innerEx = new Exception("FileNotFound");
        };

}
//Lots of logic follows here
//and here
workbook.SaveAs(ExcelOutputPath, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, "password", "password", false, false);
        workbook.Close(0);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
        workbook = null;
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: You need to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's difficult to tell you what's wrong without you providing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever comes across the same issue, it is because you need to specify the same password for the `WriteResPassword` parameter when trying to open the workbook. This is required since the workbook was originally saved with a `WriteResPassword` value